# How to change defatult authentication table name "users" in cakePHP 4?

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have added the authentication plugin and changed the code as per the CakePHP 4 documentation (https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/authentication.html). by default they using "users" table for authenticating. how can I change the default "users" table to the table "clients"?

Thank You.

Comment: read https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/identifiers.html#orm-resolver

Answer (score 2):

Using Authentication ORM to solve this issue

Edit under src/Application.php

```
 // Load identifiers, ensure we check email and password fields
    $authenticationService->loadIdentifier('Authentication.Password', [
        'fields' => [
            'username' => 'staff_email',
            'password' => 'staff_password',
        ],
        'resolver'=>[
            'className'=>'Authentication.Orm',
            'userModel' => 'myStaffs',
        ],
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

In **src/Application.php** in the **getAuthenticationService** function try to add the following:

```
$authenticationService->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Form', [
    'fields' => [
        'username' => 'email',
        'password' => 'password',
    ],
    'userModel' => 'Clients',
    'loginUrl' => '/clients/login',
]);
```